# Generate valid equation from four numbers by placing arithmetic operators

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, math, equation

I'm trying to solve various puzzles of recursion and one problem I came across is Equation Generator. I'm unable to understand how to solve this problem. The problem statement is like this.

> You are given a 4-digit number. For example, 1234. Now, you've got to
> make an equation out of it, by placing arithmetic operators and an
> equal-to sign in between the digits without changing order of the numbers.
>
> 1. 1=2+3-4
> 2. 1-2=3-4
> 3. 12=3*4
> 4. 12/3=4
> 5. 1^2+3=4

I would like to write a function that generates first equation that it can find and return it in C# or Java. Can any one give a clue or pointer as to how to solve this problem recursively?

Comment: Show us what you've done, and what is not working for you. Have a go first.

Comment: @Rots I am unable to decide where to begin actually. I will keep trying, will edit the question once I can make some progress. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: looks like some people have some ideas for you below. Good luck!

Comment: This looks like homework, so I'll just give a hint: For each 4-digit number, there are exactly 2*3*5^2 = 150 possibilities.

Comment: (Or 2*6^3 = 432, if we allow things like "2=2=2=2".)

Comment: Your examples do not match the description of the problem. In example 3 there is an operator which is not between any two numbers, but your problem description didn't say anything about placing operators to the left of the 1. You will find these problems much easier to solve if they are *unambiguously stated*.

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan nah, this isn't my homework. may be someone's, I stumbled upon it over internet so just got curious.

Comment: @EricLippert I agree about with your comment about ambiguity. I just didn't see the ambiguity till you pointed it out. Will do the necessary edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the task into three different subtasks:

- Generate all combinations of operators (seems that the numbers are always in the same order. Consider `=` as an operator)
- Evaluate a single combination of operators to determine whether true or false
- Filter all combinations using the evaluation

See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G) for generating combinations.
Finally, after you also have an evaluation function...

```
var results = GetCombinations().Where(comb => Evaluate(nums, comb)).ToList();
```

Note to all that I'm intentionally brief in order to avoid spoon-feeding.

Answer (score 4):

> Can any one give a clue or pointer as to how to solve this problem?

Yes. In addition to all the other good suggestions here: Read "How To Solve It" by Pólya. The book is about how to solve math problems but much of the advice in there is applicable to programming problems.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It

The suggestion of Pólya's that best applies to your problem is **solve a simpler problem**.  For example, can you solve this problem?

> You are given a 4-digit number. For example, 1234. Now, you've got to make an equation out of it, by placing an equal-to sign in between the digits without changing order of the numbers. For example:

```
1=234
12=34
123=4
```

Of course all of those equations are *false*, but clearly if you cannot solve the problem of generating false equations with no operators then you cannot solve the harder problem of generating true equations with operators. Solve the easier problem, and that will give you insights into how to solve the larger problem.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the name of the book. As I stated, most of the solutions except one are based on brute force. I'm actually trying to solve it recursively. Recursion isn't my area of strength that is the reason I'm picking up problems that can be solved recursively and fighting with them.

Comment: @Buddha: I don't really see how this problem is amenable to a recursive solution; can you explain?  What's the base case and what's the recursive case?

Comment: I think you are asking a wrong person :) I'm actually trying to figure out answers to these exact questions. This question I have got is in a presentation shared from one of the university lectures(I'm not from that class) couple of years back where they have given problems that get progressively harder to solve with recursion. I have solved 6 of them, I'm dumb struck at this problem. I will give answer when I can find. Base case may be when we have found an equation that can be successfully evaluated. I have to find the recursive case.

Comment: @Buddha: Well, there is some call for recursion here, but it is very limited. For example, suppose you go with a solution where you enumerate all equations and then filter out the false ones. In order to evaluate the truth of an equation you're going to have to parse it. You could write a recursive descent parser, but the longest expression that can be on one side of the equals sign will have a maximum of two operators, so recursion is a bit of overkill. Same with evaluating the parsed expression.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You could:

- generate strings and then attempt to parse and evaluate them as equations to see if they are syntactically valid and "true", or
- generate and evaluate equation trees, evaluate them and then unparse them to Strings if they are "true".

Either approach has challenges ... but discovering and solving them is your job :-)

Comment: Never heard of equation trees. I will do research on it, thanks.

Comment: An equation tree is simply a tree that represents an equation.  Its analogous to an expression tree ... or a parse tree representation of any programming language.

Answer (score 1):

My old math teacher used to play this game with the date everyday.  Funny.

Anyway, the key is to step through every possible equation sequentially.  (I know it's a recursive problem but hear me out)

Something like this:

recursivefunction(sequence):

if valid sequence return

```
 foreach operator position  
   foreach operator  
      recursivefunction(sequence with new operator)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some hints for you:

1. Enumerate all equations. After this step, you will get "1+2=3+4","1=2+3-4","1+2-3^4" etc.
2. Delete all of invalid equations. After this step, you will get "1+2=3+4","1=2+3-4" etc.
3. Evaluating all valid equations and see it's equals or not. After this step, you will get "1=2+3-4" etc.

Comment: Thanks Sayakiss. Most of the answers are similar. I will give it a shot.

Comment: @Buddha So vote me up plz...?

Comment: Why generate non-equations in the first place? Why not simply generate only valid equations?

Comment: @EricLippert Both Ok...